# How to Insert Multiple Dictionary Values with an Object Using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#Step 1: Connect to MongoDB - Note: Change connection string as needed
client = MongoClient(port=27017)
db=client.cltest
#Step 2: Create sample data
names = ['Kitchen','Animal','State', 'Tasty']
company_type = ['LLC','Inc','Company','Corporation']
company_cuisine = ['Pizza', 'Bar Food', 'Fast Food', 'Italian']


# Change Names List into Dictionary Format to Insert into MongoDB
namesdict = {}
namesrange = len(names)
for x in range(0, namesrange):
    if names[x] in namesdict:
        continue
    else:
        namesdict['names'] = names[x]

    #Step 3: Insert namesdict object directly into MongoDB via insert_one
result=db.reviews1.insert_many(namesdict)
    #Step 4: Print to the console the ObjectID of the new document
print('Created {0}'.format(result.inserted_id))
```

TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

I am new to Pymongo and Python so I am not sure if this is possible.

My goal is to take a Dictionary with several different values that was compiled from a list, and insert those values into MongoDB using the dictionary object of namesdict. I know I could manually write out each dictionary value, and insert them but looking for a more efficient way. Was hoping there may be a way to insert many at once from an array object.

Database Structure looks similar to this:
cltest (DB)
reviews1 (Document) 
Fields (_id ObjectId, names)
Column (names)
Kitchen (Value) 
Animal (Value)
State (Value)
Tasty (Value)

**Update 1**

```
dic1 = {'website': 'www.carrefax.com'}, {'website': 'Daniel Hoadley'}, {'website': 'purple'}

for item in dic1:
    collection.insert_one(item)
```

The above code allows me to enter multiple entries into the DB. Where I am still having issues is converting list(names) into a dictionary such as dic1 where all the keys are the same.

**Update 2 - Found Solution For a Single List to Dict Mass Import Values into MongoDB**

**Update 3** 
Now I am trying to take all three list convert them to dictionaries. Then insert the data from all other list into each name item so that the order of the first name corresponds with the first company type, which also corresponds with the first company cuisine entry and so on.

Updated Code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Create connection to MongoDB
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['name_of_database']
collection = db['name_of_collection']
names = ['Kitchen','Animal','State', 'Tasty']
company_type = ['LLC','Inc','Company','Corporation']
company_cuisine = ['Pizza', 'Bar Food', 'Fast Food', 'Italian']

# Build a basic dictionary & Insert into DB
for item in names:
    data = {}

    data['name'] = item
    collection.insert_one(data)

for item in company_type:
    data = {}

    data['company_type'] = item
    collection.insert_one(data)

for item in company_cuisine:
    data = {}

    data['cuisine'] = item
    collection.insert_one(data)
```

**Update 4 - Solved**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Create connection to MongoDB
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['name_of_database']
collection = db['name_of_collection']
names = ['Kitchen','Animal','State', 'Tasty']
company_type = ['LLC','Inc','Company','Corporation']
company_cuisine = ['Pizza', 'Bar Food', 'Fast Food', 'Italian']

# Build a basic dictionary & Insert into DB

for i, c, p in zip(names, company_type, company_cuisine):
    data = {}
    data['name'] = i
    data['company_type'] = c
    data['cuisine'] = p
    collection.insert_one(data)
```

Comment: you want to add this to DB? `{'names': ['Kitchen','Animal','State', 'Tasty']}`

Comment: Yes, but say the list contains over a thousand items instead of four. I am wondering how I can insert all of them at once into the database without having to type out each item.

Comment: i think you want to add this: `{'names': 'Kitchen'} {'names': 'Animal'}`

Comment: Knowing how to insert both types into Mongodb would be helpful. So whether its a dictionary with value of a list or all the values in a dictionary being able to add all of them with one object would make inserting all the data into the DB much easier.